# Laravel : unable to pass optional parameter in custom command getting error The "--default_value" option does not accept a value

Tags: php, laravel

unable to pass the value of the optional parameter in custom command.

```
protected $signature = 'addcolumn {table_name} {new_column} {column_type} {--default_value}';
```

i have tried you pass the optional parameter in different ways.

1.`php artisan addColumn users new_column varchar(255) testColumn`
2. `php artisan addColumn users new_column varchar(255) --default_value=testColumn`

but I'm getting error [this is a error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EsuAc.png)

thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this.

Add **=** sign after the optional parameter in the code. Without an = sign it takes it as a switch option, which don't take any arguments. If the switch option is present, its value is equal to true and if not then its value is false.

**add = sign to accept optional argument**.

```
protected $signature = 'addcolumn {table_name} {new_column} {column_type} {--default_value=}';
```

**In command line:**

```
php artisan addColumn users new_column varchar(255) --default_value=testColumn
```